# Multiple links to hyperlink string (Split and concatenate with ArrayFormula)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, flatten, google-query-language

I'm trying to figure out how to make a formula to turn links in one cell into hyperlinks in another
From cell A1, A2 etc I'm trying to get cell B1, B2 etc using the Split and concatenate formulas. But it's not possible to process each link to make a "wrapper" and then wrap it back into one cell

A1

```
https://link.com/xxxxxx1, https://link.com/xxxxxx2, https://link.com/xxxxxx3
```

A2

```
https://link.com/xxxxxx1, https://link.com/xxxxxx2, https://link.com/xxxxxx3, https://link.com/xxxxxx4, https://link.com/xxxxxx5
```

B1

```
   <a href="https://link.com/xxxxxx1">Button 1</a>, <a href="https://link.com/xxxxxx2">Button 2</a>, <a href="https://link.com/xxxxxx3">Button 3</a>
```

B2

```
<a href="https://link.com/xxxxxx1">Button 1</a>, <a href="https://link.com/xxxxxx2">Button 2</a>, <a href="https://link.com/xxxxxx3">Button 3</a>, <a href="https://link.com/xxxxxx3">Button 4</a>, <a href="https://link.com/xxxxxx3">Button 5</a>
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v8dYt6CIgwnlcc5HKJLNvuAcLZI0IKRTInsprs56hsU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, "<a href="""&SPLIT(A1, ", ")&""">"&
 "Name "&SEQUENCE(1, 3)&"</a>"))
```

[image]

---

arrayformula:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A1:A="",,
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, ", "))="",,"<a href="""&SPLIT(A1:A, ", ")&""">"&
 "Button "&SEQUENCE(1, 5)&"</a>,"))),,9^8))), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention ArrayFormula

Comment: @O1R answer updated